# How does TeenSafe iOS App Access Text Messages?

Tags: ios, iphone

Today I saw a news feature on the TeenSafe app. They showed features such as locking out an iPhone and eavesdropping on the text messages sent by a phone. I understand how this might be possible on Android but how can this be done on a non-jailbreaked iPhone?

Answer (score 2):

This is interesting, but it sounds kind of scary though knowing someone else is tracking your every move. Anyway, I read their website and I saw this:

> **How does TeenSafe work**
>
> TeenSafe Control uses Mobile Device Management (MDM) Protocol, similar to the way corporations secure devices used on their networks in order to protect their network from Internet threats. An MDM certificate is installed on your teen’s iPhone and paired with the TeenSafe Control App on your iPhone, giving you the power to control it remotely. TeenSafe Control’s proprietary method of incorporating MDM makes it difficult for your teenager to disable or remove it. In cases where they find a way, we will alert you via email.

You can look up on Mobile Device Management to find out more.

Comment: Hmm, MDM can't view "SMS or iMessages". http://help.apple.com/deployment/ios/#/ior1a8f33c36

Comment: Oops my bad hahaha I didn't realise that

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I found out here:

http://www.bewebsmart.com/parental-controls/monitor-imessage-with-teensafe/

Basically, you need your teen's iCloud username and password and iCloud backup has to be enabled for the device. So no special magic here and it's not perfect.